# Oracle Database 11g Express: DBA_SCHEDULER_WINDOWS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to query the information about windows:

```
select
   window_name,
   resource_plan,
   enabled,
   active
from
   dba_scheduler_windows;
```

but I got this error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 7, columna: 4
```

This is the info from DB:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means that this view is outside of your privileges scope, so it's not visible to you.
What user do you use to query this view? you will need either a DBA role or SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to query this view.